# Schema resolution issue in Impala when you add a new column in table at start or in between

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, impala

The issue i'm facing is related to schema resolution in Impala.
Impala currently does not support resolving schema-to-file metadata by name - it does so only by index i.e *Impala looks up columns within a Parquet file based on the order of columns in the table*.

For example:

Table T1, with 2 columns [A: int and B:String]

```
A|B
1|foo
2|bar
```

Added new column [X: string]

```
  X | A | B
test| 3 |bar1
```

Impala read this table based on the index. So at index(0), there are 2 different data type -

- string(w.r.t column X in NEW data),
- int(w.r.t column A in OLD data).

In my scenario, I had Re-created the table using the updated DDL to accommodate the new column, but since I added the new column in the middle...I'm getting a error when I query it.

> File
> 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/ra/rds_data.db/slot_data/date=20210107/part-00002.c000'
> has an incompatible Parquet schema for column
> 'rds_data.slot_data.slotnumber'. Column type: INT,
> Parquet schema: optional byte_array location

The workaround that I found were:

#### 1. Use a schema resolution property

`Set PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION=name`

The PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION query option allows Impala to lookup columns within Parquet files by column name, rather than column order. **But this is required to be hit in every HUE/impala session by every user(in my org.) who will query my table.**

#### 2. Overwriting data

Since the the data in the new created table is being populated constantly via spark jobs...I'll have to move new column X at the end of the table and then overwrite the data that came after I executed the updated DDL(last 2-3 days).

Currently solution #2 is the only permanent solution that I can think...Is there any other solution/workaround in which we don't have to touch/overwrite the data and still it works for all the users in my Org?

Comment: As a variation of #2, you can overwrite only the old data to comply to a new schema no?

Comment: @mazaneicha the older schema data is of few months..whereas the new data is of past 2-3 days only...so its easier to tackle just the new data.

Comment: Sorry to ask, for workaround #2, what is the issue ? You can not adjust spark job to load into last column? This is a new column so anyways you have to modify spark job column sequence. We are doing same thing in Impala. adding column in anywhere(except in the end) is always a problem.

Comment: @KoushikRoy i'm okay with implementing solution 2, no issue in that...just wanted to know if there is any other better method to tackle this issue where I don't have to overwrite the already written data.

Comment: i see, this is a problem in my system, pls update this question if you find anything.

Comment: @KoushikRoy surely I will....as of now I've implemented solution #2, to get things going.